# How do i select random quiz 12 times and display my quiz result scores in different manners

Tags: python, arrays, printing

After Hours of research i have had a very hard time to code such criteria :

```
#select random question 12 times 
#Display highest to lowest score in (alphabetical order) 
#Display highest to lowest score 
#Display highest to lowest average

#However my quiz's coding is able to save the players name in a text file     (images will be provided) and score as well as the quiz works perfectly

#MY PYTHON QUIZ FILE AND RESULTS OF QUIZ IN TEXT FILE IN TERMS OF CLASS          IMAGE :http://gyazo.com/817bd04f8c28e66ee4c9e1f5142b01df

##THIS IS MY CODE : http://pastebin.com/bdHCcvxt

#Sorry i wasnt able to paste my code on as there was an error code
 on the site so please visit the link I provided. Thanks a lot.
```

Comment: What is your specific question or problem?  "I'm having trouble coding this" is too broad for this site.  Narrow it down - what is making it so difficult for you?

Comment: Clippy says: looks like you're doing the GCSE!

Comment: @Brionius Thanks for taking interest,one of my my problem is that i am unable to generate random question from my coding.

Comment: @HughBothwell Why is that ;) ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `input()` to input a string, use `raw_input()` instead.

here is the modified source code:

```
name=raw_input ("what is your name?")
print ("Welcome", name, ", I am heisenberg and this is my quiz")       
begin = raw_input ("To begin enter 'heisenberg''")
if begin == ("heisenberg"):
    print ("Alright GOODLUCK!")
    score = 0

    class_no = ""
    while class_no not in ["1", "2", "3"]:
        class_no = raw_input("Please enter your class - 1, 2 or 3:")  # Asks the user for an input

print ("What is 5*10")
answer = raw_input ("Enter Answer: ")
if answer == "50":
    print ("Correct")
    score = score  + 1
else:
    print ("Incorrect")
    score =  score - 0

print ("What is 5*2")
answer = raw_input ("Enter Answer: ")
if answer == "10":
    print ("Correct")
    score = score  + 1
else:
    print ("Incorrect")
    score =  score - 0

print ("What is 5*3")
answer = raw_input ("Enter Answer: ")
if answer == "15":
    print ("Correct")
    score = score + 1
else:
    print ("Incorrect")
    score = score - 0

print ("What is 22+ 84")
answer = raw_input ("Enter Answer: ")
if answer == "106":
    print ("Correct")
    score = score + 1
else:
    print ("Incorrect")
    score = score - 0 

print ("What is 20/2")
answer = raw_input ("Enter Answer: ")
if answer == "10":
    print ("Correct")
    score = score + 1
else:
    print ("Incorrect")
    score = score  - 0

print ("What is 20/5")
answer = raw_input ("Enter Answer: ")
if answer == "4":
    print ("Correct")
    score = score + 1
else:
    print ("Incorrect")
    score = score - 0

print ("What is 1.1*4 ")
answer = raw_input ("Enter Answer: ")
if answer == "4.4":
    print ("Correct")
    score = score  + 1
else:
    print ("Incorrect")
    score = score - 1

print ("What is 7/7")
answer = raw_input ("Enter Answer: ")
if answer == "1":
    print ("Correct")
    score = score + 1
else:
    print ("Incorrect")
    score = score - 0

print ("What is 90-9")
answer = raw_input ("Enter Answer: ")


if answer == "81":
    print ("Correct")
    score = score + 1
else:
    print ("Incorrect")
    score = score - 0

print ("What is 41+51")
answer = raw_input ("Enter Answer: ")
if answer == "92":
    print ("Correct")
    score = score + 1
else:
    print ("Incorrect")
    score = score - 0

print ("What is 1 - 5")
answer = raw_input ("Enter Answer: ")
if answer == "-4":
    print ("Correct")
    score = score + 1
else:
    print ("Incorrect")
    score = score - 0

print ("What is 10/2")
answer = raw_input ("Enter Answer: ")
if answer == "5":
    print ("Correct")
    score = score + 1
else:
    print ("Incorrect")


print ("Thank you for playing my quiz", name,"you have scored,", score,"out of 12 points")

with open("class%s.txt" % class_no, "a") as my_class:
        my_class.write("{0}\n".format([name, score]))
```

here is the output:

```
what is your name?suraj
('Welcome', 'suraj', ', I am heisenberg and this is my quiz')

To begin enter 'heisenberg''heisenberg
Alright GOODLUCK!

Please enter your class - 1, 2 or 3:1
What is 5*10

Enter Answer: 50
Correct
What is 5*2

Enter Answer: 10
Correct
What is 5*3

Enter Answer: 15
Correct
What is 22+ 84

Enter Answer: 106
Correct
What is 20/2

Enter Answer: 10
Correct
What is 20/5

Enter Answer: 4
Correct
What is 1.1*4 

Enter Answer: 4.4
Correct
What is 7/7

Enter Answer: 1
Correct
What is 90-9

Enter Answer: 81
Correct
What is 41+51

Enter Answer: 92
Correct
What is 1 - 5

Enter Answer: -4
Correct
What is 10/2

Enter Answer: 5
Correct
('Thank you for playing my quiz', 'suraj', 'you have scored,', 12, 'out of 12 points')
```

note: you might want to use dictionary or a list to store question and answers and then cycle through them and compare their corresponding answers instead of manually typing in each question and each answer.

Comment: Many thanks for the help, it seems you have edited this code in python 2.7 ,I ve checked it on my python 3.3 it did not work but it works on 2.7, I would like this code in 3.3 as it is more efficient to code upon 3.3 compared to 2.7 if i am correct? My main concern is that I want to shuffle these 12 questioins randomly 12 times, as well as when you are done with the quiz I would like the result to be displayed in (via the saved notepad/text file result, all classes displayed ) 
highest to lowest score in (alphabetical order) 
highest to lowest score 
highest to lowest average

Comment: this is how the code saves my results in classes: http://gyazo.com/817bd04f8c28e66ee4c9e1f5142b01df

Comment: Not to mention Thanks a lot for helping me and showing interest in my coding dilemma, thankyou

Comment: > shuffle 12 questions, you will need to use the `random` library and a dictionary to store the questions and answers,
>sort & show in text file: it is simple once you do the random part, just write a function to do so, check http://www.github.com/thewhitetulip/samplepythonscripts, there is a `video.py` which randomly plays videos from a set of videos, will be of help to you